# asp.net mvc list

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint

Are there any "list" manager applications for asp.net mvc (or vanilla asp.net) that are similar to say:

- Sharepoint Lists
- Create your own list on google sites

I would prefer open-source!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about just using the Windows Sharepoint Services 3.0 library? It's not open source but you do get most of the Enterprise level benefits of MOSS / Sharepoint without requiring any of the expenses of licensing other than the windows server.

If you're looking for a decent open source alternative then I can highly recommend the [Umbraco content management system](http://umbraco.com/). You can use the editor view to create lists of document / page types under a page node and then write a simple ascx within the page template which iterates over the page's child nodes and list them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

[The Orchard Project](http://www.orchardproject.net/) is an open source CMS based on the ASP .NET platform.  It may contain what you are looking for.

Comment: no generic lists there unfortunately